# Will using [attribute*=value] selectors in the CSS affect the performance and optimization of a site?

Tags: javascript, css, optimization, content-management-system, loading

I was recently told by a tech lead to utilize this approach instead of Javascript for web development.  I understand that JavaScript often slows down a website. I'm wondering if CSS has any similar when using attribute selectors to change elements of a website built out from a template in a proprietary CMS.

Comment: If it can be done with CSS, that is a better solution. There are plenty of blog posts out there that talk about css selector performance and bottle necks.

Comment: I would expect that most selectors that require pattern matching rather than looking for exact matches will be slower. `*=` might be optimized better because it can be done using a B-tree.